# Using SFINAE to check function std::to_string exists for a type

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I want to create a function template that is specialized for types that may have `std::to_string` applied to them, another for classes for which I have defined a `mylib::to_string`, and let any types for which it may not fall through to other implementations or specializations.

Example:

```
// I only want this to be found if std::to_string exists for ItemType
template<typename ItemType>
void func(ItemType &i)
{
     std::cout << std::to_string(i);
}

// I only want this to be found if mylib::to_string exists for ItemType
template<typename ItemType>
void func(ItemType &i)
{
     std::cout << mylib::to_string(i);
}

// And finally, I'd like to be able to fall through to anything that has a << defined for streams
template<>
void func<MyClass>(MyClass &i)
{
     std::cout << MySpecialConverterFunc(i);
}
```

I always have problems with `std::enable_if` syntax. How would you add it to the first template?

Comment: FYI, editing a post so much days later and invalidating existing answers is severely frowned upon on SO. Asking a new question would have been better.

Answer (score 5):

For SFINAE you need not to specialize, but to overload. Which is saner than dealing with specializations anyway (those have quirks). SFINAE is a mechanism to guide overload resolution, not for choosing explicit specializations of function templates.

As for the check itself, you don't need `enable_if` really. Just a little bit of expression SFINAE will do:

```
template<typename ItemType>
auto func(ItemType &i) -> decltype(std::to_string(i), void())
{
     std::cout << std::to_string(i);
}

void func(MyClass &i)
{
     std::cout << MySpecialConverterFunc(i);
}
```

In the above code, `decltype` is applied to a comma expression. The left hand side is `std::to_string(i)`, if it isn't well-formed, the whole expression isn't well formed, and we get a substitution error, making the compiler discard that overload (the "not an error" part). If it's well-formed, the right hand side is a `void()` literal, so `decltype` resolves to `void` as you intended.

When substitution fails, all we are left with is the second overload, so it's picked. It would have been picked for this case anyway, because non-template overloads are always favored in overload resolution if the signature is the same. But adding a check to better guide the compiler in other cases is not a bad idea in and of itself.

Comment: I don't see how I can use this to provide one function for all classes which have a std::to_string() function defined, and another for ones where there is a MyStringFunct::to_string(), and yet another for another class of objects.

Comment: @bpeikes - Then you have another question, which is not the question you originally asked here. Nevertheless, the way I constrained the first overload may be used to consider another, and a third. If it's still unclear to you, I suggest you make a new post, asking a new question.

Comment: I didn't realize that my question was unclear. It didn't mean to invalidate answers by updating it. I just thought, after reading these answers, that I should make the question more detailed.

Note that I originally was pretty specific by asking how to add enable_if to the first function, which your answer did not use.

Comment: @bpeikes - Yes, you were specific. You were asking about the solution you had in mind, not about the problem. That doesn't mean a problem wasn't evident despite of that, and that other solutions aren't better.

Answer (score 2):

#### Avoid SFINAE and write simple code using the ADL rule

You can avoid having to use SFINAE by taking advantage of ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup). What ADL states is that:

> If a function and a type are both declared in the same namespace, you don't have to specify the namespace when invoking that function.

For example:

```
namespace foo 
{
    class MyClass {};
    std::string to_string(MyClass const& x) {
        return "[Element of MyClass]"; 
    } 
}

int main() {
    foo::MyClass x;

    std::cout << to_string(x); // This is legal because x is in namespace foo
}
```

If you write `to_string` functions in your namespace for your types, then you can write `func` once in terms of that:

```
template<class T>
void func(T const& t) {
    using std::to_string; 
    // This calls std::to_string if std::to_string is defined;
    // Otherwise it uses ADL to find the correct to_string function
    std::cout << to_string(t); 
}
```

In this example, `func` can be called with `foo::MyClass` because there's a `to_string` function that accepts `MyClass` in namespace `foo`:

```
int main() {
    func(10); // Prints 10; 
    func(3.1415); // Prints 3.1415

    foo::MyClass x;
    func(x); // Prints [Element of MyClass]
}
```

#### What about types in namespaces I don't own?

In this case, I'd recommend creating an additional namespace and sticking the `to_string` functions there, and then adding that as a `using` statement:

```
namespace textConvert {
    // Because we use std::to_string here, it automatically gets included
    // When we use textConvert::to_string
    using std::to_string; 

    // Convert a vector
    template<class T>
    std::string to_string(std::vector<T> const& vect) {
        using std::to_string; 

        std::string str = "[";        
        for(auto& elem : vect) {
            str += to_string(elem);
            str += ','; 
        }
        str.back() = ']';
        return str; 
    }
}
```

Then, we can update `func` to include `textConvert::to_string`, and because `textConvert` uses `std::to_string` in addition to the various custom conversion functions, both get included!

```
template<class T>
void func(T const& t) {
    // This *also* automatically includes std::to_string
    // Because we put using std::to_string inside textConvert
    using textConvert::to_string;

    std::cout << to_string(t);
}
```